# Traverse class Tree and convert to the needed type

Tags: c#, class, traversal

i have a class similar to this:

```
public class Channel
{
   public string Title {get;set;}
   public Guid Guid {get;set;}
   public List<Channel> Children {get;set;}
   // a lot more properties here
}
```

i need to convert this class tree to a the same tree structure,
but with less properties (and different names for the properties)
i.e:

```
public class miniChannel
{
    public string title {get;set;}
    public string key {get;set;}
    public List<miniChannel> children {get;set;}
    // ALL THE OTHER PROPERTIES ARE NOT NEEDED
}
```

i was thinking it would be easy traversing the tree with the following function:

```
public IEnumerable<MyCms.Content.Channels.Channel> Traverse(MyCms.Content.Channels.Channel channel)
{
    yield return channel;
    foreach (MyCms.Content.Channels.Channel aLocalRoot in channel.Children)
    {
        foreach (MyCms.Content.Channels.Channel aNode in Traverse(aLocalRoot))
        {
            yield return aNode;
        }
    }
}
```

how should i change the function so i could return a `IEnumerable<miniChannel>`
or, alternatively, is there some other way to do it?
Please notice that i cannot change the source class `Channel`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd just recursively convert the tree to the new type:

```
miniChannel Convert(Channel ch)
{
    return new miniChannel
    {
        title = ch.Title,
        key = ch.Guid.ToString(),
        children = ch.Children.Select(Convert).ToList()
    };
}
```